# Creating a scheduler/timer inside of akka typed actor

Tags: scala, akka, akka-typed

I'm trying to create a scheduler in my akka typed just to test it out, like to run every x seconds.

```
def start(): Behavior[ClientMsg] = Behaviors.setup { ctx =>
    ctx.log.info("start() called")

  ctx.system.scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(30.seconds, 5000.millis) { () =>
    ctx.self ! TestMessage(""""this is pretty cool"""")
  }  
}
```

I am getting an error saying an implicit execution context is not in scope.

Where should I get the execution context from when inside of an typed actor?
Also, is this how I should be setting up a scheduler/timer?

Answer (score 3):

Note that using `Behaviors.withTimers { timers => ... }` should be preferred over directly using the system scheduler as it handles removing scheduled sends if the actors stops etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use just `Behaviors.withTimers` or both `Behaviors.setup` and `Behaviors.withTimers`:

https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.7.0/typed/actor-lifecycle.html

```scala
object HelloWorldMain {

  final case class SayHello(name: String)

  def apply(): Behavior[SayHello] =
    Behaviors.setup { context =>
      val greeter = context.spawn(HelloWorld(), "greeter")

      Behaviors.receiveMessage { message =>
        val replyTo = context.spawn(HelloWorldBot(max = 3), message.name)
        greeter ! HelloWorld.Greet(message.name, replyTo)
        Behaviors.same
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In non-typed Akka the default `ExecutionContext` is the `dispatcher` object in the `system` object:

```
implicit val executionContext: ExecutionContext = ctx.system.dispatcher
```

I put this in a base class that I use for all Actors, along with default implicits for `Timeout` and `ActorMaterializer`.

Comment: I'm using akka typed